# Override assigns & IN operator behaviour in JEXL3

Tags: java, sql, jexl

I am trying to

1. Override assign operator(`=`) in JEXL3 with equals functionality to make it support SQL like statements to support below statement:

`WHERE A=B`

2. And SQL like IN operator support in JEXL3 so that it should support below statements:

`WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...)`

What classes I need to override to make it work. Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the JEXL syntax and interpreter to turn into a SQL one seems overly complicated; you would have to start with the grammar in [parser.jjt](https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/jexl3/parser/Parser.jjt)  but I'd advise against such an endeavour.

Comment: I am just planning to provide support for few SQLish operators . Can making changes in my own application be possible inspite of changing JEXL codebase?

Comment: Is adding a new operator support not available in JEXL @henrib

Comment: Adding new operators would require changing the grammar (again). May be http://www.slop.dev would be a better starting point for your requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks. I ended up changing the grammar itself.